# Request JS not giving the response

Tags: node.js, express, request

I'm trying to create a route in an express node app which will call an API and print the response. I'm using request.js to make the API call. I'm unable to get the response. What am I doing wrong?

```
var express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const API_URL= 'http://api.airvisual.com/v2/nearest_city';
const API_KEY= 'XXXXXXXX';

var router = express.Router();
var URL;

router.get('/getDetails', function(req, res){
var options = {
url: API_URL + '?key='+ API_KEY,
method: 'GET',
qs: {
    lat: req.query.lat,
    long: req.query.lon
}
}

res.send(request.get(options).response);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use request-promise [Refer Document](https://github.com/request/request-promise)

```
    //use npm install --save request-promise
    var rp = require('request-promise');

    router.get('/getDetails', function(req, res){

    var options = {
    url: API_URL + '?key='+ API_KEY,
    method: 'GET',
    qs: {
        lat: req.query.lat,
        long: req.query.lon
    },

json : true
}

rp(options)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
        // POST succeeded...
        res.send() // send response data 
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // POST failed...
        res.send() //send error data
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

request js does not return promise, we have to use callback for that find more doc here https://www.npmjs.com/package/request